# How to root my LG Escape?

Tags: rooting, lg-escape

I haven't been able to find any information on how to do this. The only thing I found was [this](http://redigua.com/one-click-root-tool-for-lg-escape.html), which seems a little shady and isn't even for the Escape, it's just a generic tool. I've also seen [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) but there are no LG phones listed & I'd rather not try a 'generic one-click' tool unless I know it's going to work.

Also, I'd like to be able to do it from Ubuntu. I CAN do it from Windows if I need to, but I'd much rather not.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search turns up [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1976116) on XDA.

You need to have propers drivers installed.

"Download the zip and unzip it to your desktop. Go into your phone's settings and go to developers options. Turn on USB debugging. Go back to settings and go to security. Turn on unknown sources. Now plug your phone in and run the .bat file that you just unzipped. Follow the commands on the and that should be it."

Most rooting tools are released for Windows first, and Linux/Mac only if there is considerable demand. I'd suggest getting it done on a Windows system if you have access to, rather than searching for a Linux compatible tool.

As for your comment on 'generic' tools, you should know that most tools work by exploiting known security vulnerabilities, many of which are specific to a kernel and/OR ROM version, and this may carry over to multiple devices (example would be OneClickRoot). If such a tool is reported to work for your device, you can try it.

Answer (score -1):

Thought I would share with everyone how to root Version 10i of the LG Escape.

How to Root Version v10i
 Run LG Spectrum ICS Root script (Windows version) Batch file.
 Takes about a minute

http://www.sendspace.com/file/jtcbmy

Comment: Might want to add some more information. For all I know, you (a new user) just posted a link to a random virus or malware.

Answer (score -2):

LG locked out the ability to root if you have their current firmware (10i as of my last knowledge and at time of writing). Key points from that thread are: to successfully root, you must be using firmware 10f (or presumably earlier). In that event, the rest of the 'easy root toolboxes' (I used one produced by bin4ry; [available here.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460) I believe his toolbox comes with both win and *nix binaries, but the reason *nix is irrelevant I explain below)

In conclusion: Use the information outlined in [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1976116) keeping in mind the following.

1. Ensure your firmware is 10f (if not, you must pursue the kdz and the downgrade process)
2. Use bin4ry's toolkit

Comment: Take your rants elsewhere, please.

Comment: Actually I kind of agree with him--I haven't had a very good experience with the phone either. I'll try your solution when I get the chance though.

Comment: I've cleaned up the answer, it was not unrecoverable.