# Installing LG Escape Drivers on Windows 7

Tags: usb-drivers, lg-escape

I'm the guy who posted [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36412/how-to-root-my-lg-escape). The provided answer didn't work on Ubuntu or Windows (it seemed to go into an infinite loop). I then tried SuperOneClick, and it didn't work either--then I noticed that ADB wasn't even detecting my phone. I tried installing the drivers from [here](http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-LGP870), but that didn't help. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I used the info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/559869/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0150004-click-ok-to-close-t) to fix another (relevant, if I remember correctly) problem I had, then reinstalled the drivers, rebooted, set the phone to "Camera (PTP)" mode, and let Windows do it's "installing drivers" thing. It works now.